# How to get list of graph nodes after using connectedComponents of pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, graphframes

I am learning PySpark in Python. If I use the below line of code to get components from my graph, then one column would be added to my GraphDataFrame with the component (random number). But I am curious is it possible to get a list of nodes that are connected?

```
g.connectedComponents()
```

Answer (score 1):

result is just a normal data frame, that you can group by `component`, and then collect results as list using the `collect_list` function ([doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list.html)). For example, using the example graph from graphframes:

```py
from graphframes.examples import Graphs
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

sc.setCheckpointDir("/tmp/spark-checkpoint")

g = Graphs(sqlContext).friends()
df = g.connectedComponents()

# getting the list of IDs per component
df2 = df.select("id", "component").groupBy("component") \
  .agg(F.collect_list("id"))
df2.show()
```

will give:

```
+------------+------------------+
|   component|  collect_list(id)|
+------------+------------------+
|412316860416|[a, b, c, d, e, f]|
+------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Is it possible to get list of lists from the the above graphframe? Something like [[a, b, c, d, e,f]]

Comment: yes, you can call `.collect()` on the result of it. But it work only for small graphs